# How to set a system Font in android

Tags: android, fonts

is there any way to change the font of my entire android system programatically. I goggled about the problem but I didn't find the solution can any one help me on this

note: not an application font

want to change the entire android system font.

Comment: Is this helping: http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-change-the-fonts-on-your-android-phone-32078/ ?

Answer (score 1):

It require root because you’ll be tampering with a protected system directory, specifically the `/system/fonts` directory, where font files used by your device reside. There are two manual methods for changing fonts — through the Android Debug Bridge and through a root-level file manager app.

Comment: Yes i used it but gives Broken Pipe Exception

Comment: wrap it in a try catch and tell me the IOException